# Using one parameter across multiple delete queries

Tags: ms-access, parameter-passing, sql-delete

Hi I am a newbie to access so please bear with me.

I am importing monthly data into access on a daily basis. There are have a couple of delete queries which remove the previous days data then a couple of append queries which update the table with the current days data.

Currently the delete queries are each using parameters to determine the date when the data in the relevant tables is deleted. As there is more than one delete query the same date is entered into each input box. Is there a way of utilizing the parameter information across the delete queries so that it can be entered once only?

Note the append queries are working automatically via a 2nd query which determines the relevant date to append from and I have tried this with the delete queries but i understand that 'innerjoin' can not be used here.

Thanks in advance David

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with a small form that asks for the required parameter, it can then be hidden or used to run each of the required queries:

```
 DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE aDATE <= Forms!aForm!aTextboxControl
```